# paypal direct payment api app credentials

Tags: php, paypal

It's been a while but I noticed that the PayPal developer portal has changed their layout together with the way they list API credentials and what they are called. Recently i have been tasked with moving an app with PayPal direct payment API integration to link in with another PayPal account. When i log in to the PayPal developer portal all i see is REST apps - and the information there is different to what is configured in my application.

Let me explain in further detail.

I have the following information in my app - This is what it was previously called:

```
API_USER = "api_user";
API_PWD = "password";
API_SIG = "signature";
```

This is in contrast to, (under REST apps):

1. PayPal Account - i assume this would be API_USER???
2. Client ID - is this password or signature?
3. Secret - again, is this password or signature?

Now the reason I ask, is because I cannot find any PayPal payment gateway documentation on what has changed. I would appreciate any insight anyone can possibly offer!

Comment: I don't think they're for the same thing.

Comment: ok, thx - but, does anyone know where in their developer portal i would find the direct payment api credentials that i am currently using? I asked paypal, but they still haven't gotten back to me after 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to login to your PayPal account for getting the API credentials. click [here](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1455) for steps.